# how to find a cookie, client-side, created by javax.servlet.http.Cookie

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I'm endeavouring to locate and inspect a cookie created by a server process and returned to a client. The client is accessing the server via specialized interface (ie - not a web browser). I am able to inspect the server code but at present I can not make changes to it. I do know the value of the [name] parameter being passed to the Cookie-constructor. I tried searching the client file system for anything containing the [name] value with no luck. My guess is that the [name] parameter is not included in the file name. I've also checked the java hidden directories for them to no avail. Finally, I attempted to find the file via local temporal search thusly:

```
sudo find / -mtime -.1 ! -path "*/sys/*" ! -path "*/proc/*"
```

Any thoughts on how I can find this little guy?

Comment: Are you using plain sockets as a Client? You should be able to see the cookie in an HTTP response from the Servlet.

Comment: if I'm understanding what you mean by 'plain sockets', then I don't think so. I'll take a look though, bbinabit

Comment: I just put a hook in the REST client to log the response from the server during the initial handshake - response was null. If there is a cookie being sent back, it's not showing up in the server response.

Comment: Do you have access to the response body? to the headers? Can you differentiate bwtween response codes?

Comment: What kind of rest client it is? It is important to know in order to be able to assess how the request/response are being handled at http protocol level.

Comment: forgive my ignorance - I'm still pretty new to some of this stuff. the 'type' is whatever is provided by apache. as for the response codes - I'm not sure but I think they are getting swallowed up by the server. lastly, I unfortunately can't post any of this code on SO.

Comment: do you know what the relationship is between the [name] field in the Cookie constructor and what ends up being the cookie file name? Is there some way to figure out what the file name is going to be, or is it random techno-gibberish?

Comment: Well, I can't imagine what kind of rest client you're using that is propietary code that cannot be shared or mentioned. Cookies are part of a response http message (usually contained in the header part of the message). Cookies can be any in key/value format, encrypted data, etc. I have no idea why you're assumming there must be a file somewhere. Are you assuming your "rest client" must behave like a web browser by saving data (cookies) in files?

Comment: i'm not trying to be vague - i don't know what you mean by 'type of rest client'. as for the cookie-as-file thing, i didn't realize a cookie could just reside in memory somewhere. if you post the specifics in the form of an answer, i'll investigate and mark it as accepted if it turns out you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without REST client specifics, I can only tell you that a Cookie it nothing else than plain text. A Cookie is usually stored (in memory, files, cache, hash map, etc.) by a client (web browser, etc.) by server request. A simple non technical explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#mediaviewer/File%3aHTTP_cookie_exchange.svg). Cookies are meant to be a shared state (stateful) between a client and a server.

Technically speaking, cookies are shared between client and a server by means of HTTP protocol. This protocol is nothing more thant standardized messages (with and URL, opeation code, encoding, headers and a body) that are sent over a TCP connection. Cookies are usualy shared in the headers area of an http message.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is a general explanation of how a server sends a cookie to a client, and vice versa. Scroll down to "Implementation".

It would really help if you can tell us how you're requesting web pages, content, etc. from a web server.

It seems that you're using a java server implementation, most likely apache tomcat, and you're using Servlets. Servlet implementation for cookie management does not differ of what I've already told you before.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask.

Comment: I'll dig into this and get back to you - thank you! Also, we're using java on both ends. the server is wso2. there's some SAML handshaking going that authenticates the client. as per the spec, a cookie is passed from the server to the client with an ID that must be passed back by the client every time a request is made. the credentials are valid for 30min. if the cookie is stored in memory somewhere then it would definitely explain why I can't find it in the file system anywhere :-)